# Android custom theme: different theme for landscape and portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I apply a custom theme to my activity with: `<activity android:theme="@style/MyTheme">`, in which I define the size of the ActionBarSherlock I use in this activity. Something like that:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarSize">45dp</item>                             
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">45dp</item>     
</style>
```

While this size is good for portrait mode, I find it too big in landscape mode. How can I apply a different theme in landscape mode or how could I just change the action bar size when the user uses the application in landscape orientation? Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

create two different styles.xml. Put one into res/values-port and the other into res/values-land

Comment: drawable-port and drawable-land seems to work, too... useful.